# C++ question regarding classes and default values for function arguments and recursion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, recursion, count

I need to use recursion to count the nodes in a linked list.

```
unsigned CLL::CountNodes(CNode* val)
{
    if(!val)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + CountNodes(val->next);
}
```

So when I want to count the nodes in the linked list, from say, another function, I go:

```
int main()
{
    CLL list();
    cout << list.CountNodes(list.head);
}
```

This seems a bit dodgy though, because the class should be able to count the list without me passing in a point to the head of the head of the list.  This seems straight forward with a for-loop; however, with recursion, I tried:

```
unsigned CLL::CountNodes(CNode* val = head)
{
    if(!val)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + CountNodes(val->next);
}
```

but this did not work because head is not static.  Then making head static is a problem, because I have to declare it outside the class.

Is there anyway to solve the problem?
e.g. cout << list.CountNodes();
Or must the head of the list always be passed in when using recursion?

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is always a way. You may have two [overloaded functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dhe1hce%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), for example:

```
unsigned CountNodes (CNode* val)
{
    return val ? CountNodes(val->next) + 1 : 0;
}

unsigned CountNodes ()
{
    return CountNodes (head);
}
```

I would also recommend making `unsigned CountNodes (CNode* val)` function [static](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods) since it doesn't need anything from `CLL` class, and `unsigned CountNodes ()` [method constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#Methods) because it doesn't change object's state.

And by the way, there is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) in C++ that makes life easier, code more readable and may even make it faster. So instead of:

```
if(!val)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + CountNodes(val->next);
```

... you could write like:

```
return val ? 1 + CountNodes(val->next) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a public function `int CountNodes()` that calls a private `int CountNodes(CNode*)` method with `this->head`.

```
// in class CLL
public:
    unsigned int CountNodes()
    {
        return CountNodes(head);
    }

private:
    CNode* head;
    unsigned int CountNodes(CNode* val)
    {
        if(!val)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + CountNodes(val->next);
    }
```

Now you have better encapsulation has your head data member is private and your client code can be made simpler.

```
int main()
{
    CLL list();
    cout << list.CountNodes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 functions.  The first one as written, plus   one with no arguments which calls the first with 'head' as the argument.